# Getting error in launching jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, localhost

I have installed Anaconda and when I try to launch jupyter notebook It give error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\Amartya Veer\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 268, in launch_instance
return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Amartya Veer\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
File "", line 2, in initialize
File "C:\Users\Amartya Veer\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Amartya Veer\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1720, in initialize
self.init_webapp()
File "C:\Users\Amartya Veer\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1448, in init_webapp
self.jinja_environment_options,
File "C:\Users\Amartya Veer\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 158, in __init__
handlers = self.init_handlers(settings)
File "C:\Users\Amartya Veer\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 294, in init_handlers
handlers.extend(load_handlers('notebook.tree.handlers'))
File "C:\Users\Amartya Veer\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 138, in load_handlers
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=['default_handlers'])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.tree'
```

I have tried reinstalling Anaconda in both single user and multiple users.

Comment: Track the existing issue here : https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5175

Comment: I try to downgrade my jupyter notebook version into 5.7.5 at the command prompt using this >
`pip install jupyter notebook==5.7.5`

Comment: Can you share some information on your environment?

Comment: @nrmzmh _I try to downgrade my jupyter notebook version into 5.7.5 at the command prompt using this > `pip install jupyter notebook==5.7.5`_ Why would you use pip for that, instead of Conda?

Comment: @AMC its depends on how you download your python, if you install your python using anaconda distribution, you may use conda instead of pip. since I'm installed my python from the python.org, that's why I'm using the pip